Issue with GitHub Actions and Docker: 'GitHub Personal Access Token is not set' during Electron/Firebase build
I've been trying to set up CI/CD for my project that uses Electron and Firebase, but I'm facing issues with GitHub secrets. I placed my PAT (Personal Access Token) inside a secret, but when GitHub Actions or Jenkins tries to build, I get this error:
"GitHub Personal Access Token is not set, neither programmatically, nor using env 'GH_TOKEN'".
I also suspect the issue might be related to the build process itself because when I tried to create a Docker image, Docker couldn't handle the build process either.
Additionally, Electron isn't setting the icon correctly, even though I'm using the required 256x256 size. During the build process, I'm also getting several permission errors related to 7-Zip.
The repository in question is private and part of an organization.
my release.yml:
name: Release

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v*.*.*'

jobs:
  release:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Setup Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: '16'

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm install

    - name: Build
      run: npm run build

    - name: Publish
      run: npm run publish
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}

    - name: Create Release
      uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
      with:
        files: |
          dist/*.exe
          dist/*.yml
        body_path: release-info.md
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}

    - name: Generate release info
      run: |
        echo "Release information for version ${{ github.ref_name }}" > release-info.md
        echo "Download your app from the assets below or from: [Google Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ozNzQRQdilmfNHfx-sga1WLCN2qo-mgP)" >> release-info.md`

I tried setting up and reconfiguring the PAT and secrets multiple times, and I also configured and reconfigured the release.yml file so that GitHub Actions could handle the secret properly.
All I want is for my Electron app to dynamically receive updates based on GitHub releases whenever I launch a new version, so the app can update itself automatically.

Which step gives this error?

Your workflow should work without
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}

